# How can I apply a CSS Tooltip to a table entire row?

Tags: css, tooltip

I'm trying to apply a CSS Tooltip to a table entire row not just to a cell but I can't figure out how.

Right now I'm only be able to apply a tooltip over a cell (as you can see on the snippet). Is it possible to apply a CSS Tooltip to a `<tr>` element? How?

[This new gif shows exactly what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4joH1.gif)

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title>W3.CSS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    
    <style>
    
    .tooltip {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .tooltip .tooltiptext {
      visibility: hidden;
      width: 120px;
      background-color: none;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 6px;
      padding: 5px 0;
      
      /* Position the tooltip */
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -60px;
    }
    
    .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
      visibility: visible;
    }
    </style>
    
    <body>
    
    <div class="w3-container">
      <h2>Directory Test</h2>
    
      <table class="w3-table-all w3-hoverable">
        <thead>
          <tr class="w3-light-grey">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
    
        <tr>
          <td><div class="tooltip">Name #1<span class="tooltiptext"><img src="http://arsil.games/images/logo-02.png"></span></div></td>
          <td>Director #1</td>
          <td>152</td>
          <td>Email #1</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve, all you need to do is insert your tooltip div into each of the table's cells in that row, like so:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title>W3.CSS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    
    <style>
    
    .tooltip {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .tooltip .tooltiptext {
      /*visibility: hidden;*/
      display: none;
      width: 120px;
      background-color: none;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 6px;
      padding: 5px 0;
      
      /* Position the tooltip */
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -60px;
    }
    
    .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
      /*visibility: visible;*/
      display: block;
    }
    </style>
    
    <body>
    
    <div class="w3-container">
      <h2>Directory Test</h2>
    
      <table class="w3-table-all w3-hoverable">
        <thead>
          <tr class="w3-light-grey">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
    
        <tr>
          <td><div class="tooltip">Name #1<span class="tooltiptext"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eC8m7Cc.png"></span></div></td>
          <td><div class="tooltip">Director #1<span class="tooltiptext"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eC8m7Cc.png"></span></div></td>
          <td><div class="tooltip">152<span class="tooltiptext"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eC8m7Cc.png"></span></div></td>
          <td><div class="tooltip">Email #1<span class="tooltiptext"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eC8m7Cc.png"></span></div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

However, I don't think you really understand what's going on here. This is not a "CSS tooltip" (no such thing exists). All it is is a simple HTML element styled with CSS such that it displays itself whenever you hover over its parent element. So, wherever you want there to be a tooltip, you'll need to add that `class="tooltip"` div (and its child `span` element).

It's also worth noting that the formatting of this div seems somewhat sloppy to me. In your CSS you've styled the tooltip with `visibility: hidden` rather than `display: none`. The difference between these two is that elements with `visibility: hidden` still take up space (have width and height) whereas elements with `display: none` don't "take up space". I believe that for a tooltip the desired option would be `display: none`, since tooltips are generally just supposed to be overlayed over the webpage's elements. (The code snippet I've provided has changed `visibility: hidden` to `display: none`.)

Comment: First of all thanks. I got confused about CCS tooltip because I saw a few terms on other sites, so thanks for the explanation.

I want the "tooltip" to appear if I put the mouse on any part of the row and not just the text of each cell, and also I would like to show the image under the first column of the row.

I have uploaded a new image that shows exactly what I'm looking for.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title>W3.CSS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    
    <style>
    
    .tooltip {
    position: relative;
    /* display: inline-block; */
    }
    
    .tooltip .tooltiptext {
      visibility: hidden;
      width: 120px;
      background-color: none;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 6px;
      padding: 5px 0;
      /* Position the tooltip */
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -60px;
    }
    
    .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
      visibility: visible;
    }
   
    .tooltip-relative {
    position: relative;
    }

    </style>
    
    <body>
    
    <div class="w3-container">
      <h2>Directory Test</h2>
    
      <table class="w3-table-all w3-hoverable">
        <thead>
          <tr class="w3-light-grey">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
    
        <tr class="tooltip">
          <td><div class="tooltip-relative">Name #1<span class="tooltiptext"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/eC8m7Cc.png"></span></div></td>
          <td>Director #1</td>
          <td>152</td>
          <td>Email #1</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```